# c# RestClient ending up in error while sending a Post Request with XML as Parameter

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, httpclient, rest-client

I am trying to update HttpResults to ALM Octane using the RestClient , It is ending up is XML not adhering to XSD .

When I Use the Postman, It runs fine. But C# code is failing.

XML - >

```
<test_result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <release_ref id="123" />
  <product_areas>
    <product_area_ref id="233" />
  </product_areas>
  <test_fields>
    <test_field type="Framework" value="TestNG" />
    <test_field type="Testing_Tool_Type" value="Selenium" />
    <test_field type="Test_Level" value="System Test" />
    <test_field type="Test_Type" value="Regression" />
  </test_fields>
  <environment>
    <taxonomy type="AUT Env" value="Production" />
  </environment>
  <test_runs>
    <test_run class="Login" duration="741" package="TestProject" status="Passed" name="Validate Login Page" />
  </test_runs>
</test_result>
```

API link - > [API LINK](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/octane/en/15.1.60/Online/Content/API/test-results.htm)

Code I am using at the moment.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
string ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();

String URI = "/api/shared_spaces/" + sspace + "/workspaces/" + wspace + "/test-results";

var client = new RestClient(octaneBaseUrl);
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(userId, pwd);

var request = new RestRequest(URI, Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
request.AddParameter("xmlBody", ret);

IRestResponse response = client.Post(request);
string res = response.Content;
```

Should I be including XML tags in XML before sending in POST?

Comment: What is RestClient?  Do you know how to post body content using it?

Comment: It looks like the schema needs to be in a relative path to the location of the exe file.  GET .../api/shared_spaces/<shared_space_id>/workspaces/<workspace_id>/test-results/xsd  What is the schema location when you run in Postman.

Comment: XSD is not placed anywhere yet . I just ensured that xml adhere to XSD using online validators , And it runs fine using the POSTMAN.

Comment: How can i add XML declaration of right type at top ?